# How to reduce # of columns SQL has to look through while joining 2 tables?

Tags: sql

I'm joining two tables together using an inner join, but given that these tables are billions of rows long, I was hoping to speed up my query and find a way to reduce the columns the sql has to comb through. Is there a way to, in a join, only have sql search through certain columns? I'm understand you can do it through SELECT, but I was hoping rather than select columns from the join, that I could reduce the # of columns being searched from.

Ex)

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.suite = t2.suite
  AND t1.region = t2.region
```

Currently table1 and table2 both have over 20 columns, but I only need the 3 columns from each table.
I'm using presto btw. Thanks and stay safe :)

Comment: You haven't tagged your specific database but with most RDBMS that work with rows (as opposed to columns) the storage system deals with entire rows; SQL is a declarative language and you tell it what columns you require (NOT *), how it gets the data is mostly not a concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create indexes on each table for both `suite` and `region` in the same index, plus an `INCLUDES` clause for any additional result columns you need, SQL Server can complete the query using only the indexes. This is called a **covering index**, and it will help performance for the query by increasing the number of "rows" (index entries) which fit in an 8Kb page verses an entire real row, which therefore also reduces the total number of page reads to complete the query.

Be aware, though, that you pay this cost by extra work at INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE time to keep the indexes up to date, extra storage needed for the indexes, and extra cache RAM use if any part of the indexes end up in the cache buffer. With potentially billions of index entries, that cost could be significant, and may outweigh the gains for this one query, or may require updates to your server capacity planning.

Comment: Thanks for answering! When I use a covering index, does this exist completely within my query, or does it make changes to the datatables I'm accessing? I'm an intern so don't want to break anything

Comment: An index is something that exists as part of the database, not part of a query. Adding an index will increase the storage and RAM use by the server, which could be a concern. It's also worth looking at what indexes already exist. Often there is already index that is close enough to what you need (maybe a few extra columns, for example, instead of the whole table).

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT T1.COL_1,T1.COL_2,T1.COL_3,T2.COL_1,T2.COL_2,T2.COL_3
 FROM TABLE_1 T1
 JOIN TABLE_2 T2 ON t1.suite = t2.suite AND t1.region = t2.region
```

And in the majority books about SQL-language there is a WARNING "Do not use * in the production code"

Comment: I almost posted the exact same answer, but then I saw this in the question: "`[I]  understand you can do it through SELECT`"

Comment: then I suggest to wait for clarification "but I was hoping rather than select columns from the join, that I could reduce the # of columns being searched from.". It sounds strange for me